# Thread not behaving as expected after rewrite

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I'm writing an android app to measure display lag on tvs using the mirror function on the video out. After many revisions, my code got too complex for its own good, so I scraped it and did a rewrite. My issue is that it is not behaving as expected. The square is not blinking, and the time is 0.0 and the rating is excellent. i have tested changing the ui via the thread by making the square turn different colors, that worked fine. Can someone tell me what the issue is and how to fix it? The way the app works is that you hook the device to a tv and it mirrors the display. then it changes the color of a square in the app and dose a time stamp, then it wait till the camera detects a change then dose another time stamp. using both time stamps you can figure out the delay of the tv. I have it in a loop because the camera only captures at 15ish fps, so I need to run the test multiple times to get an accurate result. The issue is that it always shows up as 0.0ms, that is an impossible number because the lag on most consumer tvs is 9ms. I get the RGB values from each camera frame.

```
   class lagTestThread extends Thread {

    @Override
        public void run () {
        long lagStartTime;
        long lagEndTime;
        long tempResult;
        final double rating;
        int x;
        long testResult = 0;
        int cnt;

        for (cnt = 0; cnt >= 100; cnt++){

        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                lagSquare.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(000, 000, 000));
            }
        });

        while (redVal >= 10.0 && blueVal >= 10.0 && greenVal >= 10.0) {
            x = 0;
        }

        redVal = 0;
        blueVal = 0;
        greenVal = 0;
        lagStartTime = System.nanoTime(); //start lagTimer start

        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                lagSquare.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(255, 255, 255));
            }
        });
        while (redVal <= 100.0 && blueVal <= 100.0 && greenVal <= 100.0) {
            x = 0;
        }
        lagEndTime = System.nanoTime(); //start lagTimer end

        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                lagSquare.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(000, 000, 000));
            }
        });

        tempResult = (lagEndTime - lagStartTime);
        if (tempResult <= testResult && tempResult != 0) {
            testResult = tempResult;
        }
    }
        rating = ((double) testResult) / 1000000.0;
        final String finalResultString = String.valueOf(rating);

        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                lagTime.setText(finalResultString);
                if (rating <= 17.0) {
                    lagRating.setText("Excellent");
                } else if (rating <= 34.0) {
                    lagRating.setText("Great");
                } else if (rating <= 51.0) {
                    lagRating.setText("Average");
                } else {
                    lagRating.setText("Bad");
                }
            }
        });
    }

}
```

I call it like this

```
 public void startTest(View view) {
        lagTestThread lagTest = new lagTestThread();
            lagTest.start();
    }
```

redVal, blueVal, greenVal declaration

```
 @Override
    public Mat onCameraFrame(CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {
        double[] rgb = inputFrame.rgba().get(100, 100);
        redVal = rgb[0];
        blueVal = rgb[2];
        greenVal = rgb[1];
        Log.i("", "red:" + rgb[0] + " green:" + rgb[1] + " blue:" + rgb[2]);
        return rgbMat;
    }
```

Comment: Please include the declarations of `redVal`, `blueVal`, `greenVal`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `runOnUiThread()` causes the Runnable to be *posted* to the UI thread, at which point the function returns immediately.  The Runnable executes at some later time.

Your code is posting events to the UI thread and checking the system time, which means you're calculating how long it takes to post events to the UI thread, not how long it takes them to run.  Also, because all the events are queued up behind one another, it's likely they will all execute in the same frame, so you will only see the result of the last `setBackgroundColor()` call.

If you really want to divorce your display and timing code from the UI thread, you should consider doing this with a SurfaceView, which can be updated independently of the UI thread.  (The down side of SurfaceView is that it's a lot more complicated to work with than a custom View.)

Comment: Is there a quick way to fix this, or am I gonna have to rewrite everything?

Comment: You can call `invalidate()` or `postInvalidate()` to tell the View system that it needs to redraw, and then override `onDraw()` to get some sense for when the drawing actually takes place. But the app framework is going to do stuff on its own schedule. Drawing on a SurfaceView will give the yield results, as it gives you the most control over what appears and when, and you can ignore the View UI thread. But you can't just throw frames at it or they'll queue up and spoil your timing, so you need to use Choreographer to pace the rendering.

Comment: It make way more sense to draw graphics on the display then to edit the UI. I'm a little confused, how would you implement the drawing with the Choreographer class?